# Add multiple additional predefined background colours for content elements in Typo3 with Bootstrap_package

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, typo3

I tried to add new predefined background colours according to the instructions for the bootstrap_package

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/wiki/Add-additional-Background-Colors-to-Content-Elements

It works fine with only one additional colour, adding the code from the instructions to PageTsConfig and TypoScript constants (the SCSS snippet seems to be not necessary).
However, I'm not able to make it work with more than one colour.
The pageTsConfig part seems to work (I see all the new colors as option in the backend editor).

```
TCEFORM {
    tt_content {
        background_color_class {
            addItems {
                red = Red
                white = White
                hblau = Herth-Blau
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the change in the CSS (through the constants of the extension) does not work.
I tried this code there:

```
plugin.bootstrap_package.settings.scss {
    frame-backgrounds = ( hblau:(background: #0092d0, link-color: #e0efff, link-hover-color: #ffffff),
                          white:(background: #ffffff, link-color: #e0efff, link-hover-color: #ffffff),
                          red:(background: #ff0000, link-color: #ffeeee, link-hover-color: #ffffff)
     )
}
```

Does any body else have an idea, what I'm doing wrong here?

Any help highly appreciated.

kind regards
Chris

Comment: Have you tried to write all the values on a single line?

Comment: Hey Riccardo, you are right ;) https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues/999

Comment: I will write a complete answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are writing TypoScript code, you are using the assignment operator "=" and you have to write all the values within the same line; I'll borrow some lines from the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax.html)

> **Value assignment: The “=” operator**
>
> This simply assigns a value to an object path.
>
> Rules:
>
> Everything after the = sign and up to the end of the line is considered to be the value. > In other words: You don’t need to quote anything!
>
> Be aware that the value will be trimmed, which means stripped of whitespace at both ends

Example:

```
myObject.myProperty = value 2
```

If you want to use multiline values, you have to use the **"()"** operator and write

- the  opening parenthesis on the same line of the object
- the value assigned on a new line (or multiple lines)
- and the closing parenthesis on new line

> **Multi-line values: The ( ) signs**
> Opening and closing parenthesis are used to assign a multi-line value . With this method you can define values which span several lines and thus include line breaks.
>
> **Important**
>
> *You cannot use multi-line values in constants. They are only available in the setup part of TypoScript.*

Example

```
myObject = TEXT
myObject.value (
   <p class="warning">
     This is HTML code.
   </p>
)
```